# VBscript: Loop through all text files in a folder, delete the first and last line of each file and merge into one file

Tags: vbscript

I am a newbie and looking for a way in vb script to do the following:
I have several text files in a specific folder (C:\data), I want to loop through all the text files, delete the first and last line of each text file and then combine/merge all the files into one text file.
Your help is much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Here is what I have written so far after hours of reading/searching the web (but it ends with an endless loop):

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\data\")
Set outFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\data\out\testout.txt")

for each file in folder.Files

if lcase(objFSO.getExtensionName(file.path))="txt" then

Set testfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(file.path, ForReading)


Do Until testfile.AtEndOfStream
  If testfile.Line <= 1 Then
    testfile.SkipLine
  Else
    if Not IsEmpty(line) Then outFile.WriteLine(line)
    line = testfile.ReadLine
  End If
Loop

testfile.Close

End If

next

outFile.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `option explicit` statement. Doing that helps to reveal errors in syntax and in logic as well.

Here are some code improvement hints:

- Involve a line counter ( see `linecount`).
- `IsEmpty` function returns a Boolean value indicating whether a variable has been initialized. Did you mean *empty string*?
- Note and think about `line = ""` statements.

However, next code snippet could work. But could work as expected?

```
Set testfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(file.path, ForReading)
line = ""
linecount = 1           ' or 0 ?
Do Until testfile.AtEndOfStream
  If linecount <= 1 Then
    testfile.SkipLine
    line = ""
  Else
    if Not Trim(line) = "" Then outFile.WriteLine(line)
    line = testfile.ReadLine
  End If
  linecount = linecount +1
Loop
testfile.Close
```

**Edit** according to Ekkehard.Horner's comment (thank you):

- he is right with *5th wheel*:),
- he is right with 1st line skipping,
- the last line will not be written because `.ReadLine` *succeeds* output writing.

So the code snippet could be as follows:

```
Set testfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(file.path, ForReading)
line = ""
if not testfile.AtEndOfStream then testfile.SkipLine
Do Until testfile.AtEndOfStream
    if Not Trim(line) = "" Then outFile.WriteLine(line)
    line = testfile.ReadLine
Loop
testfile.Close
```

**Edit2**: to retain empty lines

```
Set testfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(file.path, ForReading)

set line=Nothing

if not testfile.AtEndOfStream then testfile.SkipLine
Do Until testfile.AtEndOfStream
    if Not IsObject(line) Then outFile.WriteLine(line)
    line = testfile.ReadLine
Loop
testfile.Close
```

Edited according to [this Ekkehard.Horner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507073/vbscript-loop-through-all-text-files-in-a-folder-delete-the-first-and-last-lin/28508161?noredirect=1#comment45338964_28508161)

Comment: A textstream **has** a line counter (.Line), so linecount is a 5th wheel; the first line should be skipped **before** the loop; same strategy for not writing the last line.

Comment: `if Not Trim(line) = "" Then outFile.WriteLine(line)` is still an If (and a Trim()) **in** the loop that should be avoided, especially as it will remove empty lines between the first and last (not in specs). BTW: @trospe's use of IsEmpty() is entirely correct.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Ad `IsEmpty()`: correct _as such_, but for the first file only in the `for each` loop. Starting 2nd file results to `false` thus last line of previous file will be written to output. Ad _empty lines_: "solved" long ago with an _unlike string_ (cf. edit2) but now I see better solution: `set line=Nothing` instead of `line=unlikestring` and test  `if Not IsObject(line) Then` instead of `if Not line = unlikestring then`

Answer (score 0):

What I couldn't put into the comment:

```
type 28507073.vbs
Option Explicit

Dim tsIn : Set tsIn = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(".\28507073.txt")
If tsIn.AtEndOfStream Then
   WScript.Echo "Empty file"
Else
   tsIn.SkipLine
   If Not tsIn.AtEndOfStream Then
      Dim s : s = tsIn.ReadLine()
      Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
         WScript.Echo s
         s = tsIn.ReadLine()
      Loop
   End If
End If
tsIn.Close

type 28507073.txt
1
2
3
4

cscript 28507073.vbs
2
3
```